# Code Contracts, null checks and value/reference types

Tags: c#, null, code-contracts, value-type, reference-type

***Updated post**: In order to avoid confusion about what I am and am not doing, I have edited this post radically to include a complete example of the code that causes this problem. In order to make this post readable anyway, all the code is posted at the bottom.*

---

#### Background:

I am writing a fluent interface for testing (I know it's been done, but half of the purpose is to learn how it works...), in which I want to verify that `myNumber` is between 3 and 10 with a code line like

```
myNumber.ShouldBeLessThan(10).And.ShouldBeGreaterThan(10);
myListOfCars.ShouldNotBeNull().And.ShouldBeA<IEnumerable<Car>>();
```

I think you can see by reading the second line, what it is supposed to verify. There are more complicated test cases, of course...

To enable the `.And` syntax, I have introduced a helper type called `AndHelper`, which is returned by each verification method and which has a property `And` that returns whatever was tested. So `.And` in the previous example, should return `myNumber` so I can test another condition as well.

I'm using Code Contracts, and among other things I'm verifying that the `this` argument of some of these extensions is non-null. This is that causes my problem.

---

#### My problem:

When running the Code Contract checks on my code, I get a bunch of warnings that the non-null requirement on for example `ShouldBeA<T>` cannot be verified. I've tried to solve this by subclassing `AndHelper<T>` with two classes, `ReferenceAndHelper<T>` and `StructAndHelper<T>`, and `ReferenceAndHelper<T>` has contracts that should guarantee that the non-null requirement is met. However, this does not seem to work.

For each time I use one of these test extensions, I get two warning messages. One stating that the contract "instance != null" could not be verified, and the other stating the location. The first points to the line where I use the method (for example line 2 in my first example) and the second one to the line where the contract is specified, marked with `// (1)` in my code.

---

#### My code:

Please bear with me that this part of the post is quite lengthy. I don't know what SO guidelines are on posting large chunks of code (that is still relevant), but if there is a better way, please enlighten me.

Note that there is code in this section that does not cause this specific error, but that introduces limits on the solution. For example, I must have a type (`AndHelper<T>` or a subclass) that is class/struct ignorant.

A couple of the tests:

```
// This test requires that instance != null, and therefore works
// with ReferenceAndHelper<T>
public static ReferenceAndHelper<T> ShouldBeA<T>(this object instance, string message = "")
    where T : class
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(instance != null); // (1)
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ReferenceAndHelper<T>>() != null);

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<T>(instance, message.AsNullIfWhitespace() ?? string.Format("ShouldBeA<{0}> failed.", typeof(T).Name));
    return new ReferenceAndHelper<T>((T)instance);
}

// This test should work for both class and struct types T, and therefore
// cannot decide between StructAndHelper<T> and ReferenceAndHelper<T>.
// The base class is used.
public static AndHelper<T> ShouldBeGreaterThan<T>(this T actual, T expected, string message = "")
    where T : IComparable
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<AndHelper<T>>() != null);

    (actual.CompareTo(expected) > 0).ShouldBeTrue(message.AsNullIfEmpty() ?? string.Format("ShouldBeGreaterThan failed. {0} is not greater than {1}", actual.ToString(), expected.ToString()));
    return new AndHelper<T>(actual);
}

// This is the test that returns the AndHelper<T> that .And is called on.
// It is, as you can see, in all possible ways specified that this will be a
// ReferenceAndHelper<T>, which has contracts to ensure that the value is not null.
public static ReferenceAndHelper<T> ShouldNotBeNull<T>(this T value, string message = "")
    where T : class
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(value != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ReferenceAndHelper<T>>() != null);

    Assert.IsNotNull(value, message.AsNullIfWhitespace() ?? "ShouldNotBeNull failed.");
    return new ReferenceAndHelper<T>(value);
}
```

The `AndHelper<T>` class:

```
public class AndHelper<T>
{
    protected readonly T val;

    public AndHelper(T value)
    {
        this.val = value;
    }

    public virtual T And { get { return this.val; } }
}
```

The two subclasses, `ReferenceAndHelper<T>`:

```
public class ReferenceAndHelper<T> : AndHelper<T>
    where T : class
{
    public ReferenceAndHelper(T value)
        : base(value)
    {
        Contract.Requires(value != null);
    }

    public override T And
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<T>() != null);
            return val;
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void ValueIsNotNullInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(this.val != null);
    }
}
```

and `StructAndHelper<T>`:

```
public class StructAndHelper<T> : AndHelper<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public StructAndHelper(T value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }

    public override T And
    {
        get
        {
            return this.val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `struct` constraint?

Comment: How are you going to implement `IsLessThan` if the type argument is unconstrained? What is the statement `myNumber.IsGreaterThan(3).And.IsLessThan(10);` even supposed to do?

Comment: @pstrjds: No, I hadn't. But I will!

Comment: @Jeffrey: These were just two examples that I came up with without having to look through all my tests. On `IsLessThan` and the like, I have type constraints on the extension methods that the type must be `IComparable` if I remember correctly. The statement is supposed to assert (using a test framework) that what you expect to be true when you read it out loud, actually is.

Comment: Could you change the line to be as follows, and then tell us if that affects the error: `((ReferenceAndHelper)myListOfCars.ShouldNotBeNull()).And.ShouldBeA<IEnumerable<Car>>();`

Comment: @Jeffrey: I did that change, and the error message from Code Contracts is the same. Also, even if I remove the direct cast, a mouse-over on `.ShouldNotBeNull()` shows that the compiler (and therefore Code Contracts?) knows that the return type will be `ReferenceAndHelper<T>`.

Comment: @Thomas Lycken - I think I figured it out!!! You should change your class definitions to `internal`. The static checker thinks that some other assembly is going to extend your `ReferenceAndHelper` class in a way that violates the contract. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Thomas Lycken - Actually, on further reflection, that is probably not the case, since it won't affect the code at the locations given. I still have no idea what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two `AndHelper<T>` classes with different constraints, could you simply create a `NonNullAndHelper<T>` that asserts the invariant that its value is not null?  This would only be returned by helper functions that can guarantee their result is non-null, either due to a requirement or as a side-effect of their function (like IsNotNull).  This should allow the contracts to prove.

Comment: I've tried creating a `ReferenceAndHelper<T>` and a `StructAndHelper<T>` that both inherit `AndHelper<T>`, but I can't get the contract checks to work right. The problem is in the constructors, and I can't make the `AndHelper<T>` class abstract, since I have cases where I don't want to make the decision between `class` or `struct`, but I can't get the chaining right either...

Comment: I tried this now, but it's still not working. See my updated post for the relevant code.

Comment: @Tomas, I don't see the implementation of `ShouldNotBeNull()`, but does this return a `ReferenceAndHelper<T>` as its return type?  If it only returns an `AndHelper<T>`, there is not enough context to prove the result is non-null, since you don't put that Ensures in `AndHelper<T>`.

Comment: I should maybe have included that as well, for completeness, but I am already embarrassed by the amount of code I'm posting here... :P But yes, it returns a `ReferenceAndHelper<T>` (both in terms of it's type, and in terms of the `return` statement). It even has a `T : class` constraint.

Comment: Actually, `ShouldNotBeNull()` is implemented exactly as `ShouldBeA()` except for the `Assert` statement...

Answer (score 1):

> there is no way for Code Contracts to
>   verify that And (the property on
>   AndHelper) will never return null

Why not? Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you could code something like this:

```
public class AndHelper<T>
{
    protected readonly T val;
    public T And { get { return val; } }

    public AndHelper(T value)
    {
        Contract.Requires(value != null);
        val = value; 
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void Invariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(And != null);
    }
}
```

From there out, the contract checker will ensure the And value will never be null.

Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: The only difference between your code and my current code is that your field is `readonly`. The reason this code doesn't cut it, is that `T` could be a value type, and then the comparison `value != null` gives compiler warnings (which tells me there should be a better way of doing this).

Comment: Please see my updated post for more code and some extra details on the problem. Do you have any new ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Let me parrot back what I understand: the above code works, except you get warnings inside the [ContractInvariantMethod], saying "value != null" doesn't work, because value might be a value type. If that's the case, how about using something like: Contract.Invariant(And != default(T) || typeof(T).IsValueType)?

Comment: I just tried this in a new WPF project, where I had a generic class with an invariant method, and I added an invariant that val != null, and I don't see any compiler warning. What message are you getting?

Comment: @Judah: To double-check this, I just created a console app with only the following: The classes `AndHelper<T>` and `ReferenceAndHelper<T>` as in the code above, a `Dummy` class and a program that instantiates a `ReferenceAndHelper<Dummy>` and prints `helper.And` to the console window. When verifying contracts, I get a warning "Contract invariant unproven: this.val != null" pointing to the brace ending the constructor of `ReferenceAndHelper<T>`, with a location complement pointing to the call to `Contract.Invariant()`.

Comment: @Judah: I just discovered that if I add `this.val = value` in the inherited constructor as well, the contract is proven correct. Why the difference? What about constructor chaining am I not understanding here?

Comment: Well, what about that... It doesn't matter in the "real" project whether the setting row is there or not...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I see no accepted answers, so thought I'd take a shot.

Rather than having two subclasses of `AndHelper<T>`, change your `AndHelper<T>` to be the following:

```
public class AndHelper<T>
{
    private readonly T val;

    public AndHelper(T value)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!ReferenceEquals(value, null));

        this.val = value;
    }

    public virtual T And 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            Contract.Ensures(!ReferenceEquals(Contract.Result<T>(), null));

            return this.val; 
        } 
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(!ReferenceEquals(val, null));
    }

}
```

`ReferenceEquals(object, object)` does not raise the warning for generic types but guarantees they are not null.